# Getting Nil when using UITableVIew inside ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting a `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` in this line of my code inside viewDidLoad: `self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")`

I already added an identifier to match name 'cell', see image below:
[image]

[image]

When I added the following code, the error moves to it.

[image]

Comment: Wrong image I think...

Comment: Looks like it's not a subclass of `UITableViewCell`, why are you calling this method?

Comment: Have you subclassed UITableViewCell?

Comment: No. and i don't even know how to subclass it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you haven't connected your `UITableView` property in your view controller to the outlet in the storyboard, resulting in accessing an implicitly unwrapped optional.

Comment: add `IBOutlet` to your property declaration and connect to it in the storyboard. Example: https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/

Comment: It's the same tutorial I used. That is giving me error.

Comment: I'd recommend double-checking your connection between the tableView and the view controller.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the line from viewDidLoad.

```
self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

and add this in cellForRow to dequeue the cell.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
```

If you are using prototype table view then there is no need to register cell.

Comment: There are no errors but I could see the content of the tableview